# Why do we always need to install efcore via nuget in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, ef-core-2.0

I am wondering why do we need to install EFCORE and it can't be just installed and done with with one install?

Comment: Did you want to install EFCORE once for all the projects in the whole solution?

Comment: If so, you can right-click on the solution-->`Manage Nuget Packages for Solution`, choose `EFCORE` nuget package, and then check all the projects on the right part. Then you can install it only once for all the projects. Please let us know if it works and if not, please provide more info.

Comment: Package managers are universal today in the age of agile.  Nuget for .NET assemblies.  Microsoft just isn't very interested anymore in ensuring that an installed version is properly updated and that such an update doesn't break any existing projects.  Very hard to do, they want to make it your problem.

Comment: Or did you want to the EFCORE is already in the project after you create the project template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering why do we need to install EFCORE and it can't be just
>   installed and done with with one install?

**EFCORE** can serve as an object-relational mapper (O/RM), enabling .NET developers to work with a database using .NET objects, and eliminating the need for most of the data-access code they usually need to write.

**However**, not all the projects need this function and VS does not have this job by default. So if you want your project use it, you should install EFCore nuget packages.

About your questions, I think you have two aspects:

**1)** If you want all your current projects use EFCore projects, you can perform the nuget installation procedure once. Right-click on the solution-->`Manage NuGet Packages for Solutions` and then select EFCore. After that, choose any projects which you want to install this package.

[image]

**2)** If you want to already install EFCore when you create the project, you can [customize a project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019) which contains this nuget package.

- Create a project called projecttemplate, then install EFCore.
- choose Project-->Export Template-->Project Template-->select this project
- After that, close VS Instance, you can select the project template called projecttemplate in the menu which already contains EFCore.

**In addition**, when you download the EFCore, it is downloaded only once but stored in a [global nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) folder. Every time you install the package in your project, you install it directly from the cache folder.

Comment: Yes, thank you Perry, I want to already install EFCore when I create the project, thank you for your dedication. This helped a lot!